# WordPress form action - doesn't work

Tags: plugin-development

In my WP plugin I have a simple form and corresponding function:

```
<?php

/**
 * Partial of the události
 * @package    vysledky
 * @subpackage vysledky/admin/partials
 */

    add_action( 'admin_post_udalosti', 'proved_udalosti_test' );
    function proved_udalosti_test () {
        echo "I am in my function";
    }

?>

<div id="udalosti" class="wrap">
<h3>Zadej zobrazení událostí</h3>
<form action="<?php echo admin_url('admin-post.php'), '?action=udalosti'; ?>" method="post">
<table style="line-height:70%;">
<tr><th><input type="submit" name="proved" value="Zobraz události" /></th></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

The echo string does not display, blank page instead.
Where do I make mistake?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add another action to allow anonymous (not logged in) users to submit the form.

```
add_action( 'admin_post_udalosti', 'proved_udalosti_test' );
// Allows anyone to submit this form.
add_action( 'admin_post_nopriv_udalosti', 'proved_udalosti_test' );
```

Comment: All this is running with superadmin logged-in during website administration.

Comment: Understood. If that's the case, you'll want to move the action from the template to somewhere else.